# Xcode Build and Run app works but Archive fails (Flutter)

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

As title my Flutter app works fine, also building it with Xcode works and it runs fine on devices but when I try to Archive, the app build fails.

I will show the code with the error:

```
#if __has_include(<cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>)
#import <cloud_firestore/FLTFirebaseFirestorePlugin.h>
#else
@import cloud_firestore; //Error here
#endif
```

The error is : `Module 'cloud_firestore' not found`
This is weird because if I build the app with Xcode on any iPhone it builds and runs fine, I have this problem only when archiving.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Solved, I was opening the `.xcodeproj` while I had to open the `.xcworkspace`